# Creative use of the Plancherel Theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

I need to use the Plancherel theorem to show that :

$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ab}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)} dx = \frac{\pi}{(a+b)}   $  with a,b > 0

From the Plancherel theorem I know that:
$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x)|^2 dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\mathfrak{F}(\xi)|^2 d\xi  $

So, I tried to just apply the theorem using  $  f(x) = \sqrt \frac{ab}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)} $

$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\sqrt \frac{ab}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}|^2 dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\mathfrak{F}(\xi)|^2 d\xi  $

But I don't know if I'm on the right  way, I tried to calculate the Fourier transform of $ \sqrt \frac{ab}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)} $ , but it's looks more complicated than it should be.

Is there another way of doing that using the Plancherel theorem?

Comment: Plancherel's theorem is not just for the squares of functions, you can choose the product of two distinct functions instead.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem

Answer (score 4):

You may consider the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}$ and the inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{x^2+b^2}$ or... just a partial fraction decomposition. Assuming $a\neq b$ we have
$$ \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}=\frac{1}{b^2-a^2}\left(\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}-\frac{1}{x^2+b^2}\right) $$
and by integrating both sides over $\mathbb{R}$ we get
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}=\frac{1}{b^2-a^2}\left(\frac{\pi}{a}-\frac{\pi}{b}\right) = \frac{\pi}{ab(a+b)}.$$
Considering the limit as $b\to a$ we also have $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^2}=\frac{\pi}{2a^3}$.